# How to make a delete button in rails without embedded ruby

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I have two buttons which I want to put next to each other in embedded ruby. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73896271/how-does-one-position-a-link-next-to-a-button-in-embedded-ruby), I have opted to use HTML over embedded ruby to make these buttons. My delete button looks like this:

```
<a href="<%= @post %>", class="btn btn-danger"><button>Delete</button></a>
```

In embedded Ruby, the equivilet would look like:

```
<%= button_to "Delete", @post, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-danger"%>
```

Is there a way to add `<% method: :delete %>` to my HTML button in order to make it work?

Comment: The HTML generated by `button_to` depends on the specific version of Ruby on Rails. But as a first step, it is worth noting that [`button_to` (Rails 7)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) generates HTML forms and `a` with a `button` inside. In the documentation examples from older versions [`button_to` (Rails 6.1)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) you can see that the `delete` option leads to a hidden form field.

Comment: `<a href="<%= @post %>", class="btn btn-danger"><button>Delete</button></a>` is not allowed in HTML. Links cannot contains buttons (or vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, that you need put these buttons side-by-side to each other. I see you use bootstrap you can do it in next way:
Use bootstrap class '**inner-flex**' for **div** and put there all yours buttons for horizontal outpputing

```
<div class="inner-flex">
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class:"buttons btn btn-warning"%>
  <%= button_to "Delete", @post, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-danger" %>
</div>
```